# DataGridview and MySQL Deleting rows with Checkbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a Datagridview and I want to delete a row in my MySQL database.

I have some code but I get an error, it says ID is null. My ID is a string which is the value of the ID where the columns are checked. My first column "column 0" is a checkbox column

Here is the code:

Feel free to ask specific questions if you don't understand what I am asking.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles Button2.Click
Dim RowsToDelete As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)




Try
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then

DeleteRow(row.Cells(1).Value)
RowsToDelete.Add(row)
End If
Next
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try


For Each rowtodelete In RowsToDelete
DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(rowtodelete)

next       


End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRow(ByVal ID As Integer)
Dim MySQLCon As New MySqlConnection
Dim ConnectionString As String = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=business elements"

MySQLCon.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
Dim CMD As MySqlCommand
MySQLCon.Open()
Try
CMD.Connection = MySQLCon
CMD.CommandText = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = " & ID

Catch ex As Exception

End Try

MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your exact code?  In the code above, you're setting your CommandText before you're seeting your ID.  Also, this is vulnerable to SQL Injection -- look into using parameterized queries.

Comment: Yeah I have it after it and it still says the same thing .. I don't understand what you're saying, could you explain..

Comment: See my answer to see if that doesn't help.  Doesn't use parameterized queries, but would be more efficient than running multiple deletes.

Comment: BTW -- that's assuming your ID is getting set correctly in your For Loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code, something like this should work:

```
Dim sql as String

sql = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `ID` IN ("

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then
        ID = row.Cells(1).Value
        DeleteRow(row.Cells(1).Value) 
        RowsToDelete.Add(row)
        sql += ID + ","
    End If
Next

If sql.Left(sql.Length-1) = "," Then
   CMD.CommandText = sql.Left(sql.Length-1) + ")"
   CMD.Connection = MySQLCon
   CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

Good luck.

Comment: Left is not a member of string?

Comment: @Kraxed -- might depend on your Imports (I use C# primarily) -- try this: sql.Substring(0,sql.Length-1)

Comment: @Kraxed -- see this URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Kraxed Alternatively, you could use LEFT(sql, LEN(sql) - 1) -- I think that should work too :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the code:

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim RowsToDelete As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

```
    Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then

                DeleteRow(row.Cells(1).Value)
                RowsToDelete.Add(row)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try


    For Each rowtodelete In RowsToDelete
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(rowtodelete)

    Next



End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRow(ByVal ID As Integer)
    Dim MySQLCon As New MySqlConnection
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=business elements"
    MySQLCon.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    Dim CMD As New MySqlCommand
    CMD.CommandText = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = " & ID
    MySQLCon.Open()
    Try
        CMD.Connection = MySQLCon

        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try







    MySQLCon.Close()
    MySQLCon.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For i As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

```
        Dim c As Boolean
        c = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value

        If c = True Then


            =====================================================================================

            Dim sql As String = "DELETE FROM Items WHERE ItemID=" & Int(DataGridView2(1, DataGridView2.Rows(i).Index).Value)
            '                                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            '                                                                                            
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand(sql, con)

            con.Open()
            Dim result As Integer = comm.ExecuteNonQuery
            con.Close()
           End If

    Next
```